# Strange Icon files in package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer

When looking at my project in the package explorer, there is a file called "Icon" in every Folder and package. The file is empty and has zero bites. Because of the large size of my project there are quite a lot of them that end up pushing files I want to access of the bottom of the screen, and being a general annoyance.

Why do these appear and is there any way to hide them?

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Are they real files, or are they just in Package Explorer?

Comment: they also appear in finder :/

Comment: Then I guess your question isn't about the Package Explorer...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not created these files then these were created by some framework or tool/plugin used in your eclipse. Like VSS creates vss files and SVN .svn folder and files.

Check this post [how to hide files from package explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218721/how-to-hide-files-from-package-explorer) to know how to hide files in package explorer. But note that only hiding doesn't prevent these files from pushing.

To avoid/ignore pushing these file into git repo check [this](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) also refer this post [GIT and pushing with ignored files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613681/git-and-pushing-with-ignored-files)